# "A colleague from work" vs. "a colleague at work"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Which is correct?

> - The tag showed the familiar name of a colleague **from** work.
> - The tag showed the familiar name of a colleague **at** work.

The colleague is not necessarily working at the moment the tag is shown, much rather it's just a colleague from the workplace.

Comment: By definition *colleague* means someone you work with, so you might not need the prepositional phrase at all.

Comment: However, you could have a colleague in your profession who works clear across the continent. Part of the definition is *a fellow member of a profession.* http://www.thefreedictionary.com/colleague

Answer (score 1):

I don't think *at* is incorrect, but I think *from* is the better choice.

If we were together, and I waved at someone on the street, and you asked, "Do you know him?" then I might reply:

> Yes, I know him from work.

(It's unlikely I'd say, "Yes, I know him at work.")

Besides, *at work* carries the connotation of "at the workplace" ("Can I talk with Martha now?" "No, she's *at work*.") or "busy at work" ("We must slow down in the construction zone – there are men *at work.*").

I think Shoe's comment is very astute, in that you don't need the prepositional phrase at all, but let's say the nametag showed a name familiar from somewhere else – say it's the name of a percussion player in your band.  Would you say:

> The tag showed the familiar name of a percussionist *from* our band.

or,

> The tag showed the familiar name of a percussionist *at* our band.

(Personally, I think I might use *in our band*, but *from* would be acceptable, which is another reason I prefer *from* over *at* in your example.)

There are several meanings of the word *from*, but this discussion has centered on meaning #8 in [Macmillan's](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/from) list:

> **from**: 8. belonging to a particular organization

Answer (score 0):

Neither. Just *colleague*.

> **[colleague](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/colleague)**
>   *noun* a person with whom one works in a profession or business.

Avoiding tautology,

> The tag showed the familiar name of a colleague.

---

<sup>tautology: the use of words that merely repeat elements of the meaning already conveyed</sup>